# Angular CLI routing - Doesn't work on (Apache-) Server

Tags: apache, angular, angular-cli

I'm currently learning Angular-CLI for a Project. I succeeded in creating a simple little project with some routing Objects. In dev mode with **ng serve**, everthing works just fine. I can call the localhost:port in the browser and it works with the routing.

[image: Routing when executed with ng server].

After a successful **ng build -prod** and moving all the stuff from the dist directory into my Server Folder (Apache24/htdocs), I start my Server and the main Side (mywebside) just works fine, the routing however does not... (i.e. localhost/about), instead I get a standart Error-Page as shown below:

[image: Missing Page Error]

Hope I was able to describe clearly what I did and where my problems are. I didn't posted any Code because I think the problem has to be else where.

Thank you for your help!

Manuel

### Versions:

**angular CLI**: Beta.8 (latest)

**(apache)**:  2.4.20

Comment: Did you tell apache to direct all non existing file request to your root `index.html`?

Comment: I tried PierreDuc's solution: As I understood I had to created a .htaccess-file in the htdocs-directory of the Apache-Server...
So I tried... :-)
Long story short it didn't work, so either I made a mistake (because this was my first try with .htaccess-files or there's another mistake...
If anyone has a source where its explained how to redirect non existant files to index.html with a .access-fil I'd be happy to read my self in :-) Thanks!

My code:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]`

Comment: you should add the `.htaccess` in the same map as your `index.html` file

Comment: Oh Yes you're right - I already did that (if map means directory?), before i posted the first Comment :-), just forgot to change it ... but I got the same result...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK figured it out (with help from PierreDuc!)

You have to do 2 things:

1. **add a .htaccess file:** (just like that no filename!)  in the folder where your index.html File is saved, insert this code:

`ErrorDocument 404 /index.html`

2. **Edit the httpd.conf:**

(you find the File in the Apache24/conf/ directory) search for the line:

`<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs"> [...]` -> in my Version of apache it is in line 244

a few lines further (after a few comments) you should find this line:

`AllowOverride none` -> in my Version of apache it is in line 264

change this line to

`AllowOverride ALL`

Thats it, now your Angular-CLI Website should work in the production build with routing objects

hope it might be helpful to other Developpers!

Thanks to PierreDuc!

Manuel

Comment: Ahh, yes, `AllowOverride`. Forgot about that one! Good find :)