# Is there any downside of HashLocation Strategy?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am currently learning Angular. I have implemented routers using HashLocation, because PathLocation is not working in Apache server. I went through various posts to solve that, but in the end have to settle with HashLocation for Apache.

I just want to know that if there is any downside of HashLocation, like is there any Angular feature that does not work with HashLocation and can I use HashLocation  for production ready apps?

Comment: Some might consider the resulting url uglier

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer correct me if I'm wrong but you also can't use server-side rendering with the HashLocation strategy AFAIR.

Comment: I don't know about server side rendering, but I can imagine that to be true.

Answer (score 2):

According to, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#which-strategy-is-best-

> Almost all Angular projects should use the default HTML5 style. It produces URLs that are easier for users to understand. And it preserves the option to do server-side rendering later.

Server side rendering makes your app faster and more secure.

Comment: But it (HashLocation) cant be used with Apache (at least I cant configure it). So is Angular 2 useless with majority of shared hosting, that uses apache?

Comment: @raju I don't know what setup you are using but I suggest you to take a look at angular-cli, it makes everything much easier. And here's a question answered about a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183800/angular-cli-routing-doesnt-work-on-apache-server

Comment: I set .htaccess  + httpd.conf as per the link, but still 404 page on reload.

Comment: @raju ehm I don't know about apache, I just thought the link might help.

Comment: Everything works fine on nginx. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Advantages of clean URL/ path location strategy include 
A. SEO friendliness 
B. Caching of resources or i.e static assets.

If this 2 can be ignored for your usecase, you can go with hash location strategy.

To configure path location in apache
You need to add this in your .htaccess file.

`RewriteEngine On # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR] RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d RewriteRule ^ - [L] # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html RewriteRule ^ /index.html`