# angular 4 run project from dist index without HashLocationStrategy page reload 404

Tags: angular

I want to start/load my site from http://domain/dist/index.html

I have pointed my virtual host to dist/index.html, so I can load my site using this http://domain

My app.routes.ts

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PathLocationStrategy ,LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { SelectivePreloadingStrategy } from './selective-preloading-strategy';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: "", loadChildren: "app/site/site-layout/site-layout.module#SiteLayoutModule" },
{ path: "admin", loadChildren: "app/admin/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule" },
{ path: "**",    component: NotFoundComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      { preloadingStrategy: SelectivePreloadingStrategy }
  )],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  providers: [
      { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Using above strategy, everything is fine, but I have http:/domain/admin is different part of my site, so when I directly open this from url, then it will give me 404 error. Also on all other routes, if I load it from url, it will give 404.

Now I have tried with HashLocationStrategy, With this 404 error issue solved. But If I am at http://domain/# and when I edit url on same window e.g. http://domain/#/admin then css of front layout will be there. I don't want this css at admin. It's conflict between two layout css. On second reload it's fine.

Is there any solution for that?

Any option for angular to work without hashtag and not face page reload 404 error.

Just for information I have server call to NodeJS. But I want my website first load from angular dist, not from server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's giving you a 404 error because when you type in the url and hit enter the browser requests `http://domain/admin` from your server(node.js) and node.js does not have that route, Angular handles that in the client side. To overcome this problem, you can either define **every** route on your server side or you can do something like this:

```
app.get('/*',  function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/dist' }); 
});
```

Note: the folder path to the index.html is just an example.

This will redirect every external url change to your index.html and from there on Angular will handle the routing.

As a side note I wouldn't suggest using `HashLocationStrategy` because it brakes server-side rendering which is usually necessary for production environment.
More info on this topic: [Is there any downside of HashLocation Strategy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43833103/5706293)

Comment: This solution will work if my application initiate/run from server domain/host. what I am doing, initiating/running my app from ng build generated - dist/index.html

Comment: @herr so? aren't you pointing at that index.html from your node.js code?

Comment: No, I am not pointing it from nodejs :(. I want to start/run my site from dist folder index.html, hope you get my point.

Comment: @herr I actually don't :/ How do you serve your app? Do you just double click on index.html to open it? Do you use `ng serve`? How do you open the app?

Comment: I am not using ng serve, I want to serve my app on double click of index.html from dist, which is create after ng build.

Comment: @herr then you should dig deeper into how stuff works in a web environment. How do you think a user can access your local file through the web? You need to serve/deploy it into an application server(you need to expose it to the web) so that the user can navigate to that servers url:port to see your app.